# How to save the widgets load using UiLoader?

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to save the widgets load using `UiLoader` into a `ui` variable like `Ui::MainWindowClass *ui;`?

```
UiLoader loader;
QFile file(":/file.ui");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

QWidget* form = loader.load(&file);
```

Currently i'm getting widget per widget like:

```
QFrame* frame = form->findChild<QFrame*>("frame");
QLabel* label = form->findChild<QLabel*>("label");
```

I mean a way to save all widgets at once into a variable like `Ui::MyClass *form;`, in which then could be accessed like
`form_ui->frame` , `form_ui->label` etc